# In python, how do I combine two np arrays with similar but not exactly same shape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

How do you combine two np arrays b.shape (10000,28,28,1) to the end of a.shape (60000,28,28,1) so that the result is c.shape (70000,28,28,1)?

someone suggested to use np.stack((a,b),axis=0) but I’m getting the following ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape. please advise.

Comment: Are you looking for `np.vstack()`?